# readfile() not working on image sometime

Tags: php

I have a function to read file. I want to show images while download other file types.
but I am getting bulky codes while trying to view image. Below is my code:

```
public function download($file_name=NULL){
    if($file_name == NULL):
    $file_name = $this->uri->segment('3');
    endif;

    $tr= explode(".", $file_name);
    $array = array("JPG", "JPEG", "jpg", "jpeg", "PNG", 
"png", "GIF", "gif", "tiff", "TIFF");
    if(!in_array($tr[1], $array)):
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
    else:
    readfile(BASEPATH.'../assets/images/upload/'.$file_name);
    endif;
}
```

And I am trying to view image using:

```
<img class="pull-left" src="'.$this->download($img).'" /> <!-- This is image1.jpg -->
```

I am getting these type of non readable codes:

```
�r��g��7�hi99 c�Zi�zZ����ԕ�jXn⸑�7V+�56���6��qN�(�Ub��9���>tba�,� ߕs־'K�uY��a�S��ۜ�u�b�&���Z�=�]�i���
=n�I&I�#<�{dw� mgO}a���f�h�"����+����m��n%��Mnf�
```

Please help me to find the issue.

Comment: Looks to me like you are reading the image into the src attribute in the image tag.  This will result in binary being there instead of a hyperlink to the image itself.

Comment: But Andrew, I need to do it in src, as I have to show it in page. Also I cannot directly link it to image as directory is protected using htaccess deny all method.

Comment: If it's only "sometime", then seeing TIFF. TIFF files are not viewable from a browser, it's not a browser viewable format. Try it without the TIFF file(s) and see if you still get the same error.

Comment: that is JPG file. :(

Comment: My point is, you need to nest your download function in a public facing PHP file, and link to the php file in the src.

Comment: Andrew, thanks, your suggestion working now. give me this as an answer plz